# Java UDP - Sending a string array from server to client

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

Hi and thanks in advance,

So I'm trying to take an array of JList items and convert them to a string array (which I think I've gotten right), and then I'm trying to send that string array over to my client who will then attempt to display them back into a JList on their side.

I've tried a few different things but none are working.

Here is my latest code attempt to send the string array over:

```
String[] FilesList = (String[]) lClient1Files.getSelectedValues();

FilesBuffer = FilesList.getBytes();

DatagramPacket DGPFilesResponse = new DatagramPacket(FilesBuffer,FilesBuffer.length, DGP.getAddress(), DGP.getPort());
SeederSocket.send(DGPFilesResponse);
```

The line: `FilesBuffer = FilesList.getBytes();` is causing the issue because `getBytes()` isn't applicable here.

So my questions are:
1) How do I send the array of JList items(they are names) over to the client (it doesn't particularly have to be a string array), and
2) How would I receive the list on the clients side, so that I can use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Java variables should start with a lowercase. `String[] filesList`, `filesBuffer = filesList.getBytes()`. Sounds petty, but Java programmers will answer your questions more readily if they can read your code easily.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: And yet you didn't edit your code to accommodate slim's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

One must make a binary format for the string array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos)) {
    dos.writeInt(filesList.length);
    for (String files : filesList) {
        dos.writeUTF(files);
    }
}
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

This internally for a String writes first the length in bytes, and uses `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` so any string can be written.

Reading goes with the reversed input classes.

If you think of having many clients out there, maybe with different versions,
then add in the message a *version* number.

---

***On the other side***

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(baos)) {
    int stringsCount = dis.readInt();
    String[] filesList = new String[stringsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsCount; ++i) {
        filesList[i] = dis.readUTF();
    }
    return filesList;
}
```

Comment: @slim yes, I was a bit lazy: the code is not entirely symmetrical.

Comment: Thank you. It tried the code(and fixed up the symmetry), and I'm coming up with an error: 'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;' . The error also says: at 'ClientFrame1$2.actionPerformed(ClientFrame1.java:161)' which refers to this line: 'String[] FilesList = (String[]) lClient1Files.getSelectedValues();'.     I believe the array is having trouble being converted from JList to String array, but I'm not sure. Is there possibly another way that I could do the conversion?

Comment: Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html - (1) `JList<String>` and especially (2) one should use `getSelectedValueList()` which returns a `List<String>` instead of an array.

Comment: Hi again. I tried the code you suggested, but something went wrong. There isn't an error, but I don't get anything in the array on the receiver side.  The only thing I can get is this line when I run it outside of the for loop of the client side: System.out.println(FilesList); and it gives: [Ljava.lang.String;@158ce59b

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(FilesList));` - to see the content on an array.

Comment: It just gives back this: [] . I'm assuming the array never made it through. Could that be the issue?

Comment: That was an empty array. Start with fixed sized byte buffers in the UDB, so the reading is not blocking. Etcetera. Maybe start with example code.

Comment: Hi I managed to solve the issue. Instead of passing an array of the names, I instead simply passed them one at a time with the number of names included. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The UDP payload has to be a `byte[]`. You need to choose a way to encode your data into a `byte[]`, such that it can be converted back at the receiving end.

So you need to write `encode()` and `decode()` so that unit tests like this work:

```
 @Test
 public void encodesAndDecodesStringArray() {
     String[] strings = new String[] { "foo", "bar" };
     byte[] encoded = Encoder.encode(strings);
     String[] decoded = Encoder.decode(encoded);

     assertThat(decoded, is(strings));
 }
```

There are literally hundreds of encoding schemes you could choose from. Delimiter-separated, length-separated, JSON, XML, BSON, ASN.1 ... take a look at Wikipedia's [List of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

A very simple option that might work for you is delimiter-separation:

```
public byte[] encode(String[] strings) {
    return String.join(",", strings).getBytes(UTF_8);
}

public String[] decode(byte[] encodedArray) {
    return new String(encodedArray, UTF_8).split(",");
}
```

But note that this very basic scheme fails if any of the input strings contains a "," (or whatever delimiter you choose). Pick a scheme that works for you.

Consider using JSON -- there are easy to use libraries to read and write JSON. Readable ASCII in network traces is often convenient. The space overhead is not that high. It's ready for arbitrarily complex hierarchical data structures.

Consider that if you change the structure of the data produced by your sender, the receiver must also change. If that matters, consider encoding a protocol version into what you send (it might be enough to just say "the first two bytes are the version", and always stick a `0x0001` in there to start with).