# Java UDP - converting a received datagram packet back into an array of strings(names)

Tags: java, arrays

Hi and thanks in advance,

So I've got a UDP client and server, and I want to send an array of strings from the server to the client, but I'm getting an issue. Once I receive the array on the client side I can't find a way to convert it back from a Datagram packet into an array of strings so that I can use the array for what ever purpose.

Here is my code on the client side trying to receive and convert back the code:

```
byte[] FilesListReceiveBuffer = new byte[512];

DatagramPacket DGPReceiveResponse = new DatagramPacket(FilesListReceiveBuffer,FilesListReceiveBuffer.length);

String[] FilesList = new String[DGPReceiveResponse.getLength()];

for (int i = 0; i < DGPReceiveResponse.getLength(); ++i) 
{
    FilesList[i] = DGPReceiveResponse[i];
}
```

The line: `FilesList[i] = DGPReceiveResponse[i];`is showing an error `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to DatagramPacket`

So is there a way that I can convert the received packets back into an array of strings?

Thank you.

Comment: A datagram packet is essentially just a stream of raw bytes. How are you sending the array of strings through the datagram in the first place? Receive it in exactly the inverse way.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It doesn't show any errors, but the array is simply empty. The code I used for send and receive was the first answer in this thread of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172893/java-udp-sending-a-string-array-from-server-to-client/46173385?noredirect=1#comment79311591_46173385